# Jenkins Pipeline does not store Windows env variables from a cmd file

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins Pipeline (groovy) i try to run a windows script and use the variables set in this script afterwards.

I broke down the situation to this Pipeline attached.

Here I call "set" twice. Once before the script and once after the script.
My expectation is that i see the new variable in the second output. But the output does not change at all. I do see some (PATH, ...), so it is not just empty.

The goal is to have scripts working that set for example qt environment variables.

Does anybody know if I call the script in a "bad" manor? or sth else?! that I miss here.

```
timestamps {
parallel(

    "build_windows": {
        node('winddk-build') {

            stage('create bat file') {
                bat """
                    >mybat.cmd  echo set MYVAR=1234
                    >>mybat.cmd echo cmd /k
                """
            }

            stage('run bat file') {
                bat """
                    set

                    cmd /k mybat.cmd

                    set
                """
            }

            stage('clean up bat file') {
                bat """
                    del /Q /S mybat.cmd
                """
            }
        }
    }
)
```

}

Comment: `cmd /k mybat.cmd`

change to

`call mybat.cmd` 

helped. my main goal is not reached yet... but there might be some more of those differences. i will post my results here

Comment: i found my issue!! ;-)

if you set: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, it will release all variables set during that script. removing this solved my issue.